# npm - Pass arguments from CLI through multiple scripts

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

Let's say I have the following in a file called `print-last-arg.js`:

```
console.log(process.argv[process.argv.length-1])
```

And the following scripts in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "print_a": "node print-last-arg.js",
  "print_b": "npm run print_a"
}
```

When I run `npm run print_a -- --foo=bar`, I get `--foo=bar` as expected.

However, `npm run print_b -- --foo=bar` gives me no output.

How do I pass the CLI arguments from `print_b` to `print_a`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a command line argument to a nested script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495116/how-to-pass-a-command-line-argument-to-a-nested-script)

Comment: Agreed, @RobC - didn’t find that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you just have to add an extra `--` on the end of `print_b`, which will tell npm to pass whatever arguments `print_b` got to `print_a`. So,

```
"scripts": {
  "print_a": "node print-last-arg.js",
  "print_b": "npm run print_a"
}
```

becomes

```
"scripts": {
  "print_a": "node print-last-arg.js",
  "print_b": "npm run print_a -- "
}
```

Voilà! Now `npm run print_b -- --foo=bar` prints `--foo=bar` as expected.