# pass arguments to target script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using forever-monitor nom module to run `sample.js` script forever. I am trying to send arguments from `index.js`(where I am using below code to initialize forever-monitor module) to target script i.e. `sample.js`. There is an option for this i.e. `args` however, when I am trying to send arguments with this option and access that argument in `sample.js` file it returns `undefined`. **How can I pass argument and access it in target script using forever-monitor?**

```
let forever = require('forever-monitor');

let child = new (forever.Monitor)(‘sample.js', {
    'silent': false,
    'args': ['foo']
});

child.on('exit', () => {
    console.log(‘sample.js has exited.’);
});

child.start();
```

**UPDATE**

Since I am passing arguments from one javascript file to another not from command line for that reason it is not a duplicate.

Comment: This looks fine on the surface. Can you show us how you read arguments in `sample.js`? That may be the problem.

Comment: @AndyRay using `console.log(foo);`

Comment: That's not how you read arguments from a node script

Comment: If you mean process.argv then there is no such this as `foo` there too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments)

Comment: @AndyRay Well I am passing argument using script not via command line. Therefore, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Please post your `sample.js` code.

Comment: @FrankerZ it only has one line i.e. `console.log(foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `sample.js`. To get console arguments, you need to use [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv):

```
console.log(process.argv[1]); //Should echo 'foo'
```

Comment: it echos path to the node which is in my home folder. And `process.argv[1]` echos path to index.js file.

Comment: @2619 I've updated my code. The first element of `process.argv` (`process.argv[0]`) will be the execution path. You should use `process.argv[1]` instead.

Comment: and `process.argv[2]` echos undefined. :-(

Comment: Should be `process.argv[1]`.

Comment: Nope it is not in this case :-(

Comment: `console.log(process.argv[1]);` is outputting `undefined`?