# How can my grunt task see if --verbose flag is on?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a Grunt task and if the `--verbose` command line flag is on, I want to echo some more info to the console.

Finding out if that flag is on isn't possible with `grunt.option('verbose')`. It also doesn't appear to be anywhere in `grunt.package`.

How can I see, from within a task, if the user has the verbose flag set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments)

Comment: I posted an answer for you, but also flagged you question as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments/4351548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is imho because `grunt.option` works only for a grunt used flags, it doesnt take every shell argument you provide.

The esiest module-free solution is to parse your flag from `process.argv`, that returns an array.
Your flags would start at position **2**, so if `--verbose` is the first argument, you would claim it by `process.argv[2]` [How do I pass command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351548/2765745)

You can easily test it by creating a javascript file

```
  var args = process.argv;
  process.argv.forEach( (val, index, array) => {
        var flag = val.replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'), '');
        console.log(flag);
  });
```

and calling it in your shell

```
node testParams.js --argument1 -t.
```

The outcome will look like this

```
hakim@cortana:~/Sites/DOODLINGS $ node testParams.js --verbose -t
/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.5.0/bin/node
/Users/hakim/Sites/DOODLINGS/testParams.js
verbose
t
```

With some googling, you can find module to extract params for you. I dont use grunt so cant help you much there.