# How to pass .json file name as argument to command line in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, terminal

I run app.js with command `node app.js`

It executes `const inputData = require('./input.json');`

Is it possible pass file name as argument to `const inputData = require('./file.json');` from command line? I mean:

`node app.js file.json`

I am totally new to this trickery, have no theoretical point. From where I should start? Many thanks for all possible help.

Much obliged,

Comment: you have `process.argv` to access cmdline arguments https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351548/3410584. Then simply `require` with the good index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to access arguments, and [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) or [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) to read file content.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Non-blocking example with fs.readFile
const fileNames = process.argv.splice(2);

fileNames.forEach(fileName => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(fileName, data);
  });
});

// Blocking example with fs.readFileSync
const fileName = fileNames[0];
console.log(fileName, fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8'));
```

Comment: Why I can't put `console.log(fileName, fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8'));` into `const`?