# Nodejs: Need to assign the command line parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

Example of request:

```
node index.js --DIR="/Downloads" --PATTERN=\.js
```

- I found out that **process.argv** store all command line params. But
  I'm can't assign some elements of **process.argv** to *DIR* and *PATTERN* constant.
- And the order params can be different.

Comment: There's really not much more to say than "`process.argv` stores all command line parameters".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Look into [Commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.argv` stores command line parameters, yes. But they're just plain strings. Node doesn't know what you want to do with them; you'll need to parse them yourself. You'll loop through `process.argv.slice(2)`, figure out which constant is being assigned, handle any quoting or escaping weirdness, and do the assignment manually.

Or, if you don't feel like reinventing the wheel, use something like [Yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs):

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;

console.log(argv.DIR);      // /Downloads
console.log(argv.PATTERN);  // \.js
```