# How to pick up a variable from a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am wondering if there is a way to save a variable from a command like this:

`!name nameOfPerson`

`!age ageOfPerson`

and then save it to a database?

What would be a better way to handle this? maybe an array?

Comment: You can take in arguments when you start the program https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments

Comment: @forJ This is a discord bot command, not a terminal command. Also I'm asking how it would be done

Comment: @forJ The arguments would be `nameOfPerson`, `ageOfPerson`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try listening on the `message` event.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message

You can split each message into an array of words, and then add logic for each of your commands based on the first index.

```
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('message', message => {
  let msg = message.content.split(' ') // Split on space

  if (msg[0] === '!age') database_save_logic(message.author, msg[1])
  if (msg[0] === '!name') database_save_logic(message.author, msg[1])
})
```

Comment: I don't actually have any experience in using databases I'll come back to this answer once I've learnt a bit more