# Get command line arguments in nodejs programm

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get the arguments passed through command line to my nodejs application. I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-nodejs-program) and tied to use the same suggested method. In app.js this is my code

```
var task = require('./task');

const args = process.argv;
path = agrs[0];
console.log("path :"+ path);
task.start(path);
```

I get an error `agrs is not defined`

Comment: You have a simple syntax error in your code: `path = agrs[0];`; `agrs` is indeed undefined, while `args` is.

Comment: As @DamagedOrganic said - spelling mistake on `path = agrs[0];`
Should be `path = args[0];`