# How to run second node.js server from same folder with alternative configuration

Tags: node.js, configuration

I would like to run a second node.js server (using same code) running from the same directory as the first.  I use the default.json file in the config folder for the  1st server and use the config library, ie

```
let config = require('config');
```

for the first server.

What is the recommended way to specify an alternative config file.  Could you specify a custom config file to use from the command line?   How would I do this in node.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments to a Node.js program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program)

Comment: At some point you call server.listen(port) try calling that a second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config` is able to read different config files based on a few environmental variables.
Since you'll be running multiple instances on the same system, you'll need to change `NODE_APP_INSTANCE`:

1. Create config files like this:

   - `config/default.json`: Default configuration shared across all instances.
   - `config/default-1.json`: Specific configuration for instance 1. May override values of `default.json` and/or add new ones.
   - `config/default-2.json`: Specific configuration for instance 2. May override values of `default.json` and/or add new ones.
2. Start your node processes with individual values for `NODE_APP_INSTANCE`:

   - Instance 1: `NODE_APP_INSTANCE=1 node index.js`
   - Instance 2: `NODE_APP_INSTANCE=2 node index.js`

---

Checkout [the docs](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files) for more info.