# Node.js TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I'm writting a command line program which calculates the total price of an order, using info from a CSV file.

**Data inside sample.catalog.csv**:

```
P1,5,1000.00
P2,8,250.00
P3,15,125.00
P4,10,250.00
P5,2,2500.00
```

And the program must run from the command line with the following arguments:

Example: **$ CalculateOrder sample.catalog.csv P1 2 P2 4**

(P4 6 P10 5 P12 1 are products and quantity available from csv file)

**Total: 4151,25**

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var program = require('commander');
const csv = require('csv');
const fs = require('fs');


program
    .version('1.0.0')
    .option('-l, --list [list]', 'list of order prices in sample.catalog.csv')
    .parse(process.argv)

console.log("hello world")
console.log("list of order prices", program.list);


/* 
    To read csv file and print the data to the console:
    [node orderPrice --list input/sample.catalog.csv]
*/

let parse = csv.parse;
let stream = fs.createReadStream(program.list)
    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',' }));

var total = 0;
const vat = 23;
const totalWithVat = total * vat;

stream
.on('data', function (data) {
    let product = data[0];
    let quantity = data[1];
    let price = data[2];
    console.log(product, quantity, price);
    calculateOrder = () => {
        if (quantity > 20) {
            stream.destroy(new Error("Quantity exceeds stored amounts"));
        }
        total += price * quantity;
    }
})

.on("finish", function () {
    console.log("Total price:", totalWithVat);
})

.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error("The following error occured:", error);
})
```

I am having the following error:

```
λ node orderPrice calculateOrder sample.catalog.csv P1 2 P2 4
hello world
list of order prices undefined
fs.js:636
binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
      ^

TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at Object.fs.open (fs.js:636:11)
    at ReadStream.open (fs.js:1982:6)
    at new ReadStream (fs.js:1969:10)
    at Object.fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1923:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\order-price\orderPrice.js:31:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

I'm a Node.js newbie and any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the orderPrice you mentioned in the question?

Comment: orderPrice is my main file: orderPrice.js @eskawl

Comment: so you should be doing `node orderPrice.js --list "P4 6 P10 5 P12 1"`

Comment: `λ node orderPrice.js --list P1 2 P2 4
hello world
list of order prices P1
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\order-price\P1'` @eskawl

Comment: Oh! I see you are trying to read a file. In that case `node orderPrice.js --list Catalog.txt` would work.

Comment: Actually I just want to make simple calculations with `sample.catalog.csv` :( @eskawl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line

```
let stream = fs.createReadStream(program.list)
```

to

```
let stream = fs.createReadStream(program.argv[some number])
```

where some number is position at which you mention filename

e.g. run program with following command

```
node test.js somevar filename
```

then somenumber = 3

```
0th param > node
1st param > test.js (file to run)
2nd > somevar
3rd > filename
```

Another error:

Final code will look like

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const fs = require('fs');

console.log("hello world")
console.log("list of order prices", process.argv[2]);
let required_products=[]
for(var i=3;i<process.argv.length;){
   let temp=[]
   temp.name=process.argv[i++]
   temp.quantity=process.argv[i++]
   required_products.push(temp)
}
/*
    To read csv file and print the data to the console:
    [node orderPrice --list input/sample.catalog.csv]
*/

let stream = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2]);

var total = 0;
var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function(data){
         let product_name = data[0];
         let quantity = data[1];
         let price = data[2];

         required_products.forEach(function(product){

             if(product['name']==product_name){
               if(parseInt(product['quantity'])>parseInt(quantity)){
                 console.log('Quantity required for product '+product['name']+' '+product['quantity']+' is greater than available '+quantity);
                 process.exit(1)
               }else{
                 total += parseInt(price) * parseInt(product['quantity']);
               }
             }
         })
    })
    .on("end", function(){
         console.log("done");
         let totalWithVat = total * (1+ 0.23);
         console.log("Total price:", totalWithVat);
    }).on("error", function (error) {
        console.error("The following error occured:", error);
    })
 stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your explanation. Also, have you checked if it is calculating properly? @Shubham

Comment: check now if you can understand @RCohen

Comment: So, in my case is something like this? `node orderPrice.js 3 sample.catalog.csv`
@Shubham

Comment: I am still a bit confused. I need to calculate the price and for the command `node orderPrice -l sample.catalog.csv P1 2 P2 4` to run the calculation, I need your suggested code. Correct? @Shubham

Comment: why are you mentioning p1 2 p2 4 here ? it should be in csv file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177422/discussion-between-rcohen-and-shubham).

Answer (score 1):

It may sound glib, but program.list is undefined, which is why you can't read from it.  It is undefined because you haven't set up commander to know how it maps from the command line.  If you review examples in the [commander documentation](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/) it might provide more light (and look at the help for "variadic arguments").  You can follow [this example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-interactive-command-line-application-with-nodejs) on how to use command and action methods.

I recommend if you are just starting, don't use packages like commander if you don't need to. Your question really is about using commander.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program) provides some great hints as to how to get at command line arguments.

Comment: Okay, then why `console.log("list of order prices", program.list);` works, when I do `node orderPrice --list sample.catalog.csv`? @Micromuncher

Comment: It works because you've defined --list as an option, so it gets populated.  In your example "node orderPrice calculateOrder sample.catalog.csv P1 2 P2 4" you haven't told commander how to process the arguments. As a kludge you could access the arguments directly without commander if list is undefined.  Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

With the following directory structure:

`- ..
  - orderPrices.js
  - sample.catalog.csv`

You can execute `node orderPrices.js --list sample.catalog.csv` to make it work.

If your CSV file is located else where. You can you `path` module's `path.resolve` function to get the CSV file through its relative position in the following manner.

`fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, program.list)`