# Commnd line argument in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to node js and javascript execution in node js. I am trying to execute one small script in node js with arguments, I want to pass message and user name in function written in myTest.js

```
myTest(message, user);

function myTest(message, user) {
    console.log(message + ": "+ user);
}
```

## I am getting below error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { myTest(message, user);
                                                                 ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kp250041\Desktop\ProgramFiles\mytest.js:1:70)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Please advise.

Comment: When you call the myTest function, are you still inside the  myTest.js when you call it? or in another file?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with node.js (https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4j3bxhrg/) and you aren't even trying to access any command line arguments.

Comment: It sounds like your asking how to execute command line arguments in Node Js.  Here is a post to look at if that's the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what this error is telling you is that you are referencing the variable `message` which has not been defined. In order to define both `message` and `user` you are going to need to fetch those values from the command line arguments.

In order to do this we are going to access them via `process.argv`. Assuming that you are passing `message` first and `user` second then the resulting code would look something like this.

```
// The first argument is the node executable
// The second is the script file name
let message = process.argv[2],
    user = process.argv[3];

function myTest(message, user) {
    console.log(message + ": "+ user);
}

myTest(message, user);
```

For more information on command line arguments in Node.js please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program).