# How to convert an input of type string into type object array in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vorpal.js

I am creating a cli app & I get an input from the user : `print [{name:'joe', age:19}]` where `arg = [{name:'joe', age:19}]`

But when I do `typeof arg`, it returns `string`. I tried using `json.parse` [throws error], `slice(1,-1)` [removes outer array brackets & type remains string] and `Array.from(arg)` [splits all the brackets & letters into different elements].

So how do I convert `[{name:'joe', age:19}]` into type object array?

Code Snippet :

```
vorpal
.command('input <array>')
.action(function(args,cb) {
  let array = args.array;
  this.log(array); //returns [{name:'joe',age:19}]
  this.log(typeof array);  //returns string
  cb();
```

});

Comment: please, paste your code.

Comment: Does this post answer your question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program

Comment: @Sjoerd that should not be a problem because I am using a library called vorpal js to accept arguments but it always returns the argument as a string.

Comment: what is the error when you use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @YongQuan I get : SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 2

Comment: @YongQuan in JSON, object keys and strings must be wrapped in double quotes `"`

Comment: Can your users use proper JSON format , for example: 
[{"name":"joe", "age":19}] ?

Comment: @GrzesiekDanowski Its possible but I guess then I am forcing the user to follow a particular syntax (in this case JSON).

Comment: @Endemic you are creator of the cli and the cli requires using valid json :).

Answer (score 0):

The input that you pass is not a valid `JSON` structure that's why `JSON.parse` has shown parsing error.

```
var validInput = '[{"name":"joe","age":19}]';
console.log(JSON.parse(validInput));
```

Comment: you probably meant `var validInput = '[{"name":"joe","age":19}]';`?

Comment: So should I force the user to follow the json syntax while passing input? Isnt there a way to convert the input type to [object Array] directly?

Comment: @Endemic You have to write your custom logic then to parse this string and create an valid json.

Comment: @Kaddath yes. Sorry i miss the quotes `'`. Edit answer

Comment: you need double quotes for `"joe"` too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run Code Snippet.

```js
var obj = new Object({name:'joe', age:19});
console.log(typeof obj);
```

Comment: When I follow your method, the type changes to object but when I console.log(obj) it returns the output  -  [String: '[{name:\'arjun\',age:19}]']

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse expects keys to be in double quotes. so somehow you have to change the input to this format

```
JSON.parse([{"name":"joe", "age":"19"}])
```

and the output would be

[image]

Comment: So should I force the user to follow the json syntax while passing input? Isnt there a way to convert the input type to [object Array] directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can still try these regexes, that will convert your string into valid JSON. Be careful that it's not perfect, this version only accepts letters and numbers as keys for objects, while other characters can be valid too for object keys. You have to modify this part `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to improve it if you know a bit of regex..

```js
var str = "[{name:'joe', age:19}, {'name':'jack', age:21}, {\"name\":\"jane\", age:23}]", validJson, obj;
console.log('original string: ', str);

validJson = str.replace(/({\s*|,\s*)'?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'?(\s*:)/g, '$1"$2"$3').replace(/(:\s*)'(.*?)'(\s*,|\s*})/g, '$1"$2"$3');
console.log('modified string: ', validJson);

obj = JSON.parse(validJson);
console.log('decoded from JSON: ', obj);
```

EDIT: regex updated to support object keys defined with simple quotes (2nd object). NOTE: it keeps already well formatted JSON as it is (3rd object).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `eval`, e.g.

```
> eval("[{name:'joe', age:19}]")
[ { name: 'joe', age: 19 } ]
```