# How to pass params to node scripts from command line?

Tags: node.js

*package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "node build build_name"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {

  }
}
```

**build.js**

```
console.log("Building Code. Output File Name:", process.env.build_name);
```

**Command Line**

```
$ npm run build build_name="web"
```

I want to pass a parameter `build_name` from the command line while executing `build` script.  I will use that param inside my `build` script. Can someone tell me how to achieve this? Also if I did not pass `build_name` from the command line, can we send a default value from here `"build": "node build build_name"` instead of `build_name`.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "yargs" module.

**Step 1:**

```
 npm install yargs
```

**Step 2:**

```
 vi test.js
```

press i and copy the below code and paste it.

```
'use strict';

const args = require('yargs').argv;

console.log('Name: ' + args.name);  
console.log('Age: ' + args.age);
```

**Step 3 : Execution**

```
node test.js --name=jacob --age=45
```

**Step 4: output**

```
Name: jacob
Age: 45
```

Let me know if it helps.