# Error: Environment Vairable name is not recognized as an internal or external command in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nodeenv

I am not very experienced in Nodejs but I am trying to fetch some some information in my node app that I will pass from CMD/terminal that I will access through **process.env** in my app.

For example, I want to pass PORT NUMBER through env in my node and fetching the same using below line:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
```

and I am passing port number at the time of running node app using below command line:

```
node server.js PORT=4200
```

The above one is not working. After searching on google, many people giving solution to achieve the same by running below command line:

```
PORT=4200 node server.js
```

By running above command, I am getting error in command line as given below:

```
'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Can someone please let me know, how can I pass variable at the time of running node app and access the same in node app. I don't want to use any env file. I just only want to pass info from command line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass command line arguments to a Node.js program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program)

Comment: Powershell or command prompt? See [Setting and using variable within same command line in Windows cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/q/223104/81031)

Answer (score 0):

Command-line arguments are traditionally passed in via the `process.argv` array. `argv[0]` contains the process name `node`, `argv[1]` contains the first command line argument, etc... So, you can run:

```
node server.js 4200
```

and from node, do:

```
const port = parseInt(process.argv[1], 10);
```

See [How do I pass command line arguments to a Node.js program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4351521/4613449)

If you must use environment variables, Node's `process.env` contains the environment variables of the `node` process.
The `set` command is used to store a value in an environment var on Windows. Then run `node`:

```
set PORT=4200
node server.js
```

More examples of the `set` command can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1#examples .

Comment: When I use set PORT=4200 node server.js, system is assuming whole line as value of PORT. How can i set multiple values and run node in single line

Comment: Please set `PORT` to just `4200`, not `4200 node server.js`.