# add parameters to node script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to add some custom scripts to package.json and I want to pass filepaths as parameters to the scripts
for example i have this script

```
    "captures": "node ./interfaceVisualTesting/captures.js",
```

which requires json files:

```
const repjsonref = require('../json/report1.json');
```

I want my script to be like this

```
"captures": "node ./interfaceVisualTesting/captures.js ../json/report1.json
```

and to require the parameter in the javascript file
how can i do that ?

**EDIT**

I realized that i didn't ask the right question
what i meant is i want the path to be passed as a parameter while writing the script like this

```
`npm node-script captures <path of json>`
```

Comment: is `"captures": "node ./interfaceVisualTesting/captures.js ../json/report1.json` not working?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the path value as an environment variable

package.json

```json
"captures": "REPORT_PATH='../json/report1.json' node ./interfaceVisualTesting/captures.js",
```

```js
const repjsonref = require(process.env.REPORT_PATH);
```

Comment: sorry i asked the wrong question

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to add variables to the node script in this question [How do I pass command line arguments to a Node.js program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program)
but all i had to do was add the variables in the script when it was called

```
npm run-script captures <path1> <path2>
```

and then add them to the javascript like this

```
x=require(process.argv[2]);//path1
y=require(process.argv[3]);//path2
```