# Error: listen EACCES: permission denied --port

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am new to Node.js and was building a HTTP Application which runs on the port number given by user when executing the `index.js` file. This is the code snippet:

```
const flagValue = process.argv[2];
server.listen(flagValue);
```

This works fine when we execute `node index.js 3000` but return an error when `node index.js --port 3000` is used.

```
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1459:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '--port',
  port: -1
}
```

I would really love the explanation behind the error.
Thank you!

Comment: Because `"--port"` is not a valid port number

Comment: @JSONDerulo So how to let user enter the port number in CLI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass command line arguments to a Node.js program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program)

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful but my only issue is that `node index.js 3000` works but `node index.js --port 3000` doesn't. As a matter of fact, not only `--port` but nothing works. Permission is denied each time!

Comment: If you want to support argument syntax `--port 3000`, you need proper parsing of the arguments (assuming you want to support more arguments in future). NodeJS doesn't support this out of the box. `process.argv[2]` is just the third overall parameter, which is in your case `"--port"`, to get the port number (fourth overall parameter) you can use `process.argv[3]`. But this only works when the arguments are in a specific order, it's not suitable for more complex scenarios.

Comment: This solved it! And now I understood your point... By the way, if there is a complex scenario, do we use something like `minimist`?

Comment: Exactly, a package like minimist is a good choice for parsing arguments.