# Is there way to pass command line arguments to Next.js?

Tags: node.js, next.js, command-line-interface

I'm working on a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) (v14.0.3) project and like to pass some command line arguments with the `next dev`/`next build` commands to test different build scenarios.

I often did this for other (non-Next) Node projects, using `process.argv` (see [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program-and-receive-them)). If needed using the `--` ([see Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--)) for custom arguments. This seems not to work with Next.

```bash
> next dev --products=20
Unknown or unexpected option: --products

> next dev -- --products=20
Unknown or unexpected option: --products
```

There is the possibility to pass [Node options to Next](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-cli), but custom arguments are not allowed.

```bash
> NODE_OPTIONS='-- --products=20' next dev
node: -- is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

> NODE_OPTIONS='--products=20' next dev
node: --products= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

Is there even a way to pass custom arguments into Next.js?

I currently use the `.env` file and `process.env` to achieve what I want to do, but this is rather a hack and not very flexible.

Comment: Unfortunately, Next.js does not natively support passing custom command line arguments directly to the next dev or next build commands. The error messages you’re seeing are due to this limitation.

Comment: Using environment variables could be one way as you've mentioned, ex: `$ products=20 npm run dev`, another way is you can use `.env` file, or read from a `config.json` file.

Comment: a `config.json` might be a good compromise, at least more flexible and editable by script than the `.env`

Comment: A `config.json` approach would still not provide an easy way to set the number of e.g. products in the command line, i.e. `npm run dev -- --products=20`. I would have to change the config file first, save it, and then run `npm run dev`

Comment: You can write your own simple cli, for example a simple JavaScript file in your project root inside a folder called `bin` called `cli`. you'll make a script that will read cli commands and pass them as env variables to the next commands eg `npm run dev`. 
then you would change your package.json scripts, instead of `dev`: `next dev` you would write `dev`: `./bin/cli dev`. and then every argument you will pass should be recived by the `cli` file which will handle passing the env vars to the next app.